# Splitting Row into two rows mysql based on row value

Tags: mysql

I really dont understand this row split.

But what I am trying to do is split a row into two rows based on if the check amount is great than 0 AND the act amount is greater than 0

current mysql statement

```
Select * from checkdetail where depid = 7
```

I get this result

Field Names are:

```
Type, Amount, dealname, dealernum, serialno, invnum, actnum, actamt, detnotes
```

Values:

```
C, 88455.00 SEEGER HOMES, 9149200 BK-51-0353-I, 122361, 1140, -1696, Overpay
```

What I need is

Two Rows One one with the 88455 as the amount,

```
C, 88455.00 SEEGER HOMES, 9149200 BK-51-0353-I, 122361, 1140, 0, Overpay
```

And te other as -1696 as the amount like this,

```
C, -1696, SEEGER HOMES, 9149200 BK-51-0353-I, 122361, 1140, 0, Overpay
```

I know the statement has to do with a case statemnt and union ?

Thanks Stack Hope this makes sense

Comment: No, it doesn't.   If it's one row in the database, then that's what you get.  I don't see anything to distinguish one from the other except the amount.  Sounds like a badly normalized design.   What's the primary key?  I don't see depid in the list of field names.

Comment: All the fields are chkdetid, chkid, detid, type, amount, dealname, dearlnum, serilno, invnum, actnum, actamt, detnotes

the chkdetid is the primary key. 

its in relationship to the check table, which is in relationship with the deposit table.

Comment: Then it sounds like there are two tables that should be involved.  The query should include a JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `union all` statement:

```
select Type, Amount, dealname, dealernum, serialno, invnum, actnum, 
       0 as actamt, detnotes
from checkdetail where depid = 7
union all
select Type, actnum as Amount, dealname, dealernum, serialno, 
       invnum, actnum, 0, detnotes
from checkdetail where depid = 7
```

Comment: So if i get a row where the actamt is 0 I dont want to split that row. I only want to split a row when the actamt is greater than 0

Comment: @BrandonC -- then all you need to do is add that as additional where criteria to the second query: `where depid = 7 and actnum > 0`

Comment: @BrandonC, I am not sure what you are trying to do, you are saying you need `actamt > 0`. But in your question the example row has `-1696` which is lower than 0!